# Is it grammatically correct to say "someone being a mood "?

Tags: grammar, british-english

Is it grammatically correct to say "someone being a mood"? For example, "Michael being a mood for 5 minutes straight". And why?

Comment: People are not moods. One can *be* in a bad mood or a good mood. If someone is always in a bad mood they can be called *moody* but never a mood. Please let us know where you saw or heard this.

Answer (score 1):

@Elliot in the comments is correct for "normal" usage, the preposition *in* is used with "mood", or you can use the adjective moody.

However, recent slang does use "mood" without a preposition. The most common way might be attached to a picture, illustrating said mood, as explained by [Daily dot](https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/what-is-big-mood/) and [Slate](https://slate.com/technology/2018/01/why-almost-anything-on-the-internet-can-now-be-your-mood.html).

This can also take the form of "x is a mood", e.g. "Michelle Obama at the Oscars is such a mood". However I have never heard it in the form you describe, "... being a mood", typically the formula is just "is a mood"